# Sqlite-android: how to compare string and get id of that String from database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i have "Table_Subject" and i need to compare subject name with "table_subject"'s
subject name and return id of that subject. I do that but it not returning any value.
Here is my sample code for reference.
Please give me some hint or code.
Thanks in advance.

```
public int getSubjectId(String subjectName) 
{
    int id2 = 0;
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        String selectQuery= "SELECT  s_id FROM " + TABLE_SUBJECT;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    if(subjectName.equals(cursor.getString(1)))
                    {
                        id2=cursor.getInt(0);                       
                    }           
                  }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());
                db.close();
            }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id2;

}
```

Comment: Try adding a logger and print `cursor.getString(1)` and subjectName...

Comment: Try printing out both values (subjectName and (cursor.getString(1)). Maybe that'll help to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the SQL here instead of java, as it is easier, create an appropriate query that checks for the matching string, and returns the id:

```
public int getIdForString(String str) {
    int res;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
            }, COLUMN_STRING + "=?",
            new String[] { str }, null, null, null, null);
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        res = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
    }
    else {
        res = NOT_EXIST;
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Please note that I used many constants in this example as this is much easier and less error prone. In this case, the constants are:

- `MY_TABLE` - String, the table name
- `COLUMN_ID` - String, the name of the ID column
- `COLUMN_STRING` - String, the name of the column with the string to compare
- `NOT_EXIST` - int, -1, to indicate that it was not found.